# (jQuery) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, undefined

```
     $.ajax({
  error: function(){alert('Error retrieving candidates from database.');},
  success: function(data){
   var template = '    <div class="candidate" id="candidate-$1">\r\n\
     <div class="header">\r\n\
      <div class="picture"><a href="$2" class="target[\'_blank\']"><img src="pictures/$1.jpg" alt="$4" /></a></div>\r\n\
      <h2><a href="$2" class="target[\'_blank\']">$4</a></h2>\r\n\
      <h3>$5</h3>\r\n\
      <div class="stats">\r\n\
       <span class="alike" title="You have $6% in common with John Galt."><span class="number">$6</span>%</span>\r\n\
       <span class="similarity-graph" title="$7% of survey takers have less in common with $3 than you do; $8% of survey takers have more in common with $3 than you do.">$7,$8</span>\r\n\
       <span class="certainty-graph" title="PrezMatch.com is $9% certain that John Galt is your best match.">$9</span>\r\n\
      </div>\r\n\
     </div>\r\n\
     <div class="tabs">\r\n\
      <span class="active profile-tab"><a href="javascript:;">Profile</a></span>\r\n\
      <span class="keypoints-tab"><a href="javascript:;">Key points</a></span>\r\n\
     </div>\r\n\
     <div class="active content profile-content">\r\n\
      $10\r\n\
     </div>\r\n\
     <div class="content keypoints-content"></div>\r\n\
    </div>\r\n';
   var result = '\r\n';
   $(data).children().first().children().each(function(){
    var temp = template;
    temp = temp.replace(/\$1/g, $(this).attr('id'));
    temp = temp.replace(/\$2/g, $(this).children('link').first().html());
    temp = temp.replace(/\$3/g, $(this).attr('gender').toLowerCase() == 'm' ? 'him' : 'her');
    temp = temp.replace(/\$4/g, $(this).children('name').first().html());
    temp = temp.replace(/\$5/g, $(this).children('subtitle').first().html());
    temp = temp.replace(/\$6/g, '<span class="percent-in-common"></span>');
    temp = temp.replace(/\$7/g, '<span class="less-in-common"></span>');
    temp = temp.replace(/\$8/g, '<span class="more-in-common"></span>');
    temp = temp.repalce(/\$9/g, '<span class="percent-certain"></span>');
    temp = temp.replace(/\$10/g, $(this).children('profile').first().html());
    result += temp;
   });
   result = $(result);
   $('#candidates').prepend(result);
  },
  url: 'data/candidates.xml'
 });
```

I cannot for the life of me diagnose this problem. I have a very similar method for getting questions from questions.xml which works fine, but this one generates an error in the jquery.min.js file.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you spelled "repalce" (instead of "replace") at the $9 line? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Could I convince you to use [Douglas Crockford's version of supplant](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html)?  It's much easier to implement what you're doing using it.  In fact I'll convert your code to use it:

```
$.ajax({
    error: function() {
        alert('Error retrieving candidates from database.');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var template = '<div class="candidate" id="candidate-{id1}">\r\n\
 <div class="header">\r\n\
  <div class="picture"><a href="{id2}" class="target[\'_blank\']"><img src="pictures/{id1}.jpg" alt="{id4}" /></a></div>\r\n\
  <h2><a href="{id2}" class="target[\'_blank\']">{id4}</a></h2>\r\n\
  <h3>{id5}</h3>\r\n\
  <div class="stats">\r\n\
   <span class="alike" title="You have {id6}% in common with John Galt."><span class="number">{id6}</span>%</span>\r\n\
   <span class="similarity-graph" title="{id7}% of survey takers have less in common with {id3} than you do; {id8}% of survey takers have more in common with {id3} than you do.">{id7},{id8}</span>\r\n\
   <span class="certainty-graph" title="PrezMatch.com is {id9}% certain that John Galt is your best match.">{id9}</span>\r\n\
  </div>\r\n\
 </div>\r\n\
 <div class="tabs">\r\n\
  <span class="active profile-tab"><a href="javascript:;">Profile</a></span>\r\n\
  <span class="keypoints-tab"><a href="javascript:;">Key points</a></span>\r\n\
 </div>\r\n\
 <div class="active content profile-content">\r\n\
  {id10}\r\n\
 </div>\r\n\
 <div class="content keypoints-content"></div>\r\n\
</div>\r\n';
        var result = '\r\n';
        $(data).children().first().children().each(function(){
            var t = $(this), temp = template.supplant({
                id1: t.attr('id'),
                id2: t.children('link').first().html(),
                id3: t.attr('gender').toLowerCase() == 'm' ? 'him' : 'her'),
                id4: t.children('name').first().html(),
                id5: t.children('subtitle').first().html(),
                id6: '<span class="percent-in-common"></span>',
                id7: '<span class="less-in-common"></span>',
                id8: '<span class="more-in-common"></span>',
                id9: '<span class="percent-certain"></span>',
                id10: t.children('profile').first().html()
            });
            result += temp;
        });
        $('#candidates').prepend($(result));
    },
    url: 'data/candidates.xml'
});
```

I think this looks a lot cleaner.  You could also take a look at [jQuery templating](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) if you want to stick with a jQuery-based solution.

If you use the version in the link I posted you'll be happy to know that browsers supporting the newer version of ECMAScript will override it with their built in version, hopefully giving a nice performance increase.

Also as a general recommendation, I'd move your template declaration outside of the ajax call so that it's not recreated on each call of `success`.